# Move array item to another array on click

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, addeventlistener

I have two kinds of arrays going on which are

```
var arrayAdmins = [{"firstName": "Admin", "lastName": "User", "email": "test@1.com","password": "admin"}];
var aBlocked = [{"firstName": "Blocked", "lastName": "User", "email": "test2@2.com","password": "blocked"}]
```

To keep it simple for this question I have a button:

```
<input type="button"id="switch">
```

I then do a variable to target the button:

```
 var arraySwitch = document.getElementById('switch');
```

What I want to do is that when the button is clicked the user from the array called `aBlocked` over to `arrayAdmins`. So I'm hoping that from a certain admin panel, the admin can remove user from being blocked into being an admin.

Comment: Sorry I got a little confused, I was editing it and it was already fixed by someone else, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: use another variable as a placeholder during the switch

Comment: What if I have 2 users and I only want to move one of them but not all at once ? I´m guessing the arrayAdmins.push(aBlocked) will move everything from the array.

Comment: The only thing that worries me is how unsafe those password is

Comment: Hehe that was only for the questions purpose :)

Comment: They shouldn't even be on the frontend at all and shouldn't be saved in clear text (use md5 or sha with salt)

Comment: It´s only project for school saved in localhost so there´s no worries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users should have an "id" so you can identify them in your array, I'll suppose in your case that the email is unique

```
var arrayAdmins = [{"firstName": "Admin", "lastName": "User", "email": "test@1.com","password": "admin"}];
var aBlocked = [{"firstName": "Blocked", "lastName": "User", "email": "test2@2.com","password": "blocked"}]

var btnSwitch = document.getElementById('switch');
btnSwitch.onclick = SwitchClicked;

function SwitchClicked(){
    //Remove user from aBlocked
    var removedUser = RemoveUserByEmail(aBlocked, "test2@2.com");

    //Add the removed user to arrayAdmins
    if(removedUser != null){
        arrayAdmins.push(removedUser);
    }
}

//Will remove the first user found with this email and returns it
function RemoveUserByEmail(arrayOfUsers, email){
    for(var i=0; i<arrayOfUsers.length; i++){
        if(arrayOfUsers[i].email === email){
            var removedUsers = arrayOfUsers.splice(i, 1);
            if(removedUsers.length > 0) return removedUsers[0];            
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to have a way of targeting which user you want to move in your UI.

Then, it's just a matter of removing the user from one array and append it to the other. For exemple, if you want to remove the second user of `aBlocked` (if there was one) and add it to `arrayAdmins` you could do:

```
var unblockedUser = aBlocked.splice(1, 1)[0];
arrayAdmins.push(unblockedUser);
```